# Auto-sizing google adsense code on php site

Tags: php, html

I have a php site. I have been given code for an auto-sizing ad from google adsense. I have put this within a "div" to align it, and have created a function to echo the adsense code within my php script;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MY WEBSITE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("title.php"); ?>  
        <?php
        $googleadsensecode = '  //a function for the adsense code.  
        <div align="center"> //<div> to align the ad.
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- Responsive_TextnDisplay_20160127 -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:block"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-9232383262111727"
        data-ad-slot="4287484293"
        data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
        </div>';
        echo $googeladsensecode;
    </body>
</html>
```

However the ad is taking up the whole page, and thus is presumably not picking up on the remaining website's content.

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: Alot of people forget, you can use HTML outside of PHP tags in a HTML document :D, you don't need the variable `$googleadsensecode` only to `echo` it after you're done defining it. Instead just take the code you're echoing in PHP out of the PHP tags (without the variable definition etc...) and insert it directly into HTML *as HTML* instead

Comment: I tried that but it sadly just didn't show anything. I'm not sure if that's a separate issue but as I understand echoing it should still work.

Comment: All that `echo` does is send the exact same HTML, the way you put it in is just different so something is going wrong there (you're not pasting the right bits of HTML into the correct locations of your website)

Comment: If you want, you can show me, for your issue tho I still have to look

Comment: I tried creating a JSFiddle to see why your div is so big, but all you pretty much want to do after it's deformed is inspect element, grab the class/id attribute and style it with CSS to reduce the size, hope that helps

Comment: Hi Sidney, I've tried doing this putting the ad code in a separate php, with div in it that uses a separate css file. This unfortunately shows nothing.

Comment: No joy with JSFiddle of this; https://jsfiddle.net/branches/ss9nhkdf/